# Using f# on a mac with the dotnet cli

Tags: .net, f#, dotnet-cli

I was trying to follow https://github.com/enricosada/fsharp-dotnet-cli-samples/wiki/Getting-Started#hello-world to get started with f# and dotnet core on my mac.

```
% mkdir helloworld
% cd helloworld
% dotnet new --lang "f#"
Created new F# project in /Users/User/dotnet/helloworld.
% ls
Program.fs   project.json
```

Here, I can already tell, that there is no NuGet.Config as outlined in the tutorial I followed. Then

```
% dotnet restore
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/User/dotnet/helloworld/project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'dotnet-compile-fsc' in /Users/User/dotnet/helloworld/project.json...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /Users/User/dotnet/helloworld/project.lock.json
log  : /Users/User/dotnet/helloworld/project.json
log  : Restore completed in 2148ms.
% dotnet run
Project helloworld (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling helloworld for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.1.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0'.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet compile-fsc @/Users/User/dotnet/helloworld/obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 131

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.4439997
```

Dotnet info says

```
% dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.12
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
```

Comment: Those instructions mention (at the top) installing the .Net Core Preview 1. But https://github.com/dotnet/cli/releases lists Preview 3, whose [release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/) mentions that they're moving away from `project.json` and back to a `.csproj` format, though it's a `.csproj` format that's apparently greatly simplified from what it used to look like. Perhaps you simply need to update your .NET CLI tools to 1.0 preview 3 and try again?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue before when creating the F# project using `dotnet new --lang "f#"`

The problem is this dependency, which you should see in you `project.json` file: [dotnet-compile-fsc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-compile-fsc/).

```
"tools": {
    "dotnet-compile-fsc": "1.0.0-preview2.1-*"
},
```

At the time of writing this only supports the .Net Core 1.0.* runtime, not the .Net Core 1.1.* runtime you have installed.

To fix this you can [install the .Net Core 1.0.* runtime from here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime/lts) and run `dotnet run` again.  Both the 1.1.* and 1.0.* runtimes can be installed locally without issue.

For reference, [here is the issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/issues/42).  There is a fix but it's not on NuGet yet.

Answer (score 1):

The current `dotnet-compile-fsc` doesnt work yet with .NET Core 1.1 (current, sdk preview2.1), only with .NET Core 1.0 (LTS, sdk preview2).

You can workaround doing the `dotnet restore` like the following, using the dev feed because the new package is not yet on nuget.org

`dotnet restore -f https://www.myget.org/F/netcorecli-fsc-preview2-1/api/v3/index.json`

see https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/wiki/.NET-Core-SDK-preview2.1 for more info/workaround